# What is the gnome-open analog on XFCE desktop?

Tags: gnome, command-line, xfce

In Gnome, there's a handy command line utility `gnome-open`, that opens a specified file the same way it would be opened by the double click. Is there anything similar for XFCE?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The command [`xdg-open`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/xdg-open.1.html) works on all [freedesktop.org](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/)-compliant desktop environments. This includes Xfce and LXDE.